# PHP: return all string values for all specified tags in string

Tags: php, regex

```
function getValues($string, $tagname) {

    $pattern = "/<$tagname ?.*>([^<>]*)<\/$tagname>/";
    preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    var_dump($matches);
    return $matches;
}

getValues("<a>1</a><a>2</a><a>3</a>", "a");
```

I expect to get an array values 1,2,3 etc....

It returns:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(24) "<a>1</a><a>2</a><a>3</a>"
      [1]=>
      int(0)
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "3"
      [1]=>
      int(19)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use regex for this - use a dom parser like so:

```
<?php
function getValues($string, $tagname) {
    $return = [];
    $document = new DomDocument();
    $document->loadHtml($string);
    $elements = $document->getElementsByTagName($tagname);
    foreach($elements as $element) {
        $return[] = $element->nodeValue;
    }
    return $return;
}


var_dump(getValues("<a>1</a><a>2</a><a>3</a>", 'a'));
```

Demo with dom parser: http://viper-7.com/NBtiNC

Edit: Although, changing your regex to `/<$tagname ?.*?>([^<>]*)<\/$tagname>/` seems to work. The difference is the `?.*>` -> `?.*?>`

Demo with new regex: http://viper-7.com/4UxX0h

Comment: $return = []; complains about it.

Comment: If you have < PHP 5.4, change it to `$return = array();`